# Solving the integral of a step function

Tags: integration, riemann-integration, riemann-sum, step-function

I am dealing with a step function *S(t)*. The true functional form is not given or unknown, but what is known is that  S(t) takes a different value at each time point *t* like this below.

```
 t      S(t)    W(t)
 0      1       48.75
 1      0.996   48.6
 4      0.993   48.0
 6      0.9989  48.46 
 7      0.9986  48.32
14      0.9982  48.18
```

I know that $\int\limits_0^ts(u)\,\mathrm du= \sum_{i=2}^{i}(t_i - t_{i-1})*S(t_i)$ , Riemann sum concept.

How do I solve $\int\limits_0^t us(u)\,\mathrm du=??$ is it similar to the above Riemann sum concept, $\int\limits_0^t us(u)\,\mathrm du=\sum_{i=2}^{i}(t_i - t_{i-1})*t_i*S(t_i)$

Any advise or pointers on solving this integral is much appreciated.